# How to append json in Python List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

I want to create a JSON Python List shown as below using without repeated codes(Python functions).

**Expected Output:**

```
        Steps=[
        {
            'Name': 'Download Config File',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': [
                    'aws', 
                    's3', 
                    'cp',
                    's3://sample-qa/jars/Loads/',
                    '/home/hadoop/',
                    '--recursive'
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Spark Job',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': [
                    'spark-submit',
                    '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                    '--executor-memory', '10g',
                    '--conf', 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer',
                    '--conf', 'spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false',
                    '--master', 'yarn',
                    '--class', 'com.general.Loads',
                    '/home/hadoop/Loads-assembly-0.1.jar',
                    '20120304',
                    'sample-qa'
                ]
            }
        }
        {
            'Name': 'Spark Job',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': [
                    'spark-submit',
                    '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                    '--executor-memory', '10g',
                    '--conf', 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer',
                    '--conf', 'spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false',
                    '--master', 'yarn',
                    '--class', 'com.general.Loads',
                    '/home/hadoop/Loads-assembly-0.1.jar',
                    '20220130',
                    'sample-qa'
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Spark Job',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': [
                    'spark-submit',
                    '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                    '--executor-memory', '10g',
                    '--conf', 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer',
                    '--conf', 'spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false',
                    '--master', 'yarn',
                    '--class', 'com.general.Loads',
                    '/home/hadoop/Loads-assembly-0.1.jar',
                    '20220214',
                    'sample-qa'
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

**Attempted:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

steps = [
    {
        "Name": "Download Config File",
        "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
        "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
                "aws",
                "s3",
                "cp",
                "s3://sample-qa/jars/Loads/",
                "/home/hadoop/",
                "--recursive",
            ],
        },
    },
]

def addSteps(date):
    step = {
        "Name": "Spark Job",
        "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
        "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
                'spark-submit',
                '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                '--executor-memory', '10g',
                '--conf', 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer',
                '--conf', 'spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false',
                '--master', 'yarn',
                '--class', 'com.general.Loads',
                '/home/hadoop/Loads-assembly-0.1.jar',
                date,
                'sample-qa'
            ],
        },
    }
    return step
    
for date in ['20210801','20210807','20210814']:
    addingstep = addSteps(date)
    steps.append(addingstep)
    steps =json.dumps(steps)
    
print(steps)
```

I have attempted this implementation, but getting error please find below.

**Error:**
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Any other possibility to create this list? How to achieve this ?

Comment: Remove `steps =json.dumps(steps)`, or move it after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the indentation here:

```
for date in ['20210801','20210807','20210814']:
    addingstep = addSteps(date)
    steps.append(addingstep)
    steps =json.dumps(steps)
```

Fix:

```
for date in ['20210801','20210807','20210814']:
    addingstep = addSteps(date)
    steps.append(addingstep)

steps = json.dumps(steps)
```